# "Installing" API with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use a PHP classes I downloaded, and I have no idea how to import them to my project. I've been usually using `include()` or `require()` to import classes, but it seem a little bit more complicated. This is the folder:

[image]

I've been trying to understand the composer point and I didn't understand how to include or install it in my project.. 
I have already downloaded [this](https://getcomposer.org/) .

I'm using Xampp and developing on my windows machine. I might want to upload the final project to my web hosting (Linux) after that, and it seem that the composer just making the life harder. Anyone can help me install this API/Classes so I can use them now and later?

Comment: If the component has an `autoload.php`, require it and be done.

Comment: Then you might have a bad time, depending on its size and complexity. If it doesn't have an autoload, it does not complies with [PHPFIG standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) which is troublesome. Does it have documentation?

Comment: I understand that being thrown into using Composer is not the best experience without help. Have you read documentation? You should inform yourself about a) autoloading classes in PHP in general, the PSR-0 and PSR-4 standards b) installing and using Composer on the command line and c) then adding other people software to your project. The more complicated part is to let go of the habit of including all the code manually. Can you explain where you have problems understanding how to proceed?

Comment: Absolutely agree with Sven. I really hope that you will soon get away from the thought that composer might make things harder, especially when you are talking about moving/deploying your application to another machine :)